# Notify User(View) from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model with some business logic added into the DBContext class. This logic checks to see if a person will be notified of the changes to the database.If the notification fails because an email address is not on file,I want pass info back to the controller that called the db.SaveChanges so that the controller can then accordingly pass it to the view.

how do i access the controller called from within a model?

Comment: If a model update, Use `tryUpdateModel(Model);` or if only model add `ctx.savechanges()` use `try catch`

Answer (score 0):

the controller action should have the logic in there to catch the notification issue (exception)  
and then respond with the appropriate view thereafter